# Trouble expanding div with iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to embed an iframe by Livestream in my site that I can toggle to two different sizes. So when a button is pushed the video is expanded to a bigger size, without the video playback stopping.

I've tried doing this by using the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggle").click(function() {
        $("#container").toggleClass("wide");
    });
});
```

I've tested this with the embedcode of a YouTube video and this works. But for some reason the Livestream widget doesn't expand. 
Please see the fiddle for the exact code I'm using:
http://jsfiddle.net/ULauz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an `iframe`, setting the width/height of the outer `div` will not reset the `iframe` width/height. You have to explicitly set the width/height of the `iframe`. Also the player inside the iframe has its own width/height set when `iframe` loaded so even if iframe is resized the player will not be resized. Due to domain constriants you can set the players width/height.

Try this which is actually resizing the `iframe` but player is not resized.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggle").click(function() {
        $("#container").toggleClass("wide");
        $("#container iframe").height(340).width(540);
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ULauz/3/

Comment: So basically, the flash element within the iframe won't resize? Does that mean it's not possible to resize the widget without interrupting playback?

Comment: Yes, you cannot access the elements inside `iframe` if they are not in the same domain.

Comment: Ok, but how come it is possible to do this with a YouTube video?

Comment: I think youtube video doesn't play in an `iframe`. Thats why it resizes as the outer container(`div`) resize.